# Run docker container extracted from Ubuntu in Windows

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu machine that contains a docker container.
For reasons I cannot run the server, but I can access the files trough a file explorer.
I found the docker folder in var/lib/ is there a way to copy and run that on a windows machine in a windows docker?

I cant run any of the docker commands on the Linux system as I cannot access it.

Is it possible or do I have to have the system running?
Thanks in advance! Sorry if it's a bad question I'm very new to this and can't find a similar enough case.

Comment: The containers run from images and so if you can get access to the image, you can run it on any docker environment

Comment: Can you build the image from the overlay2 files?

Comment: It might be easier to figure out how to start the machine in another context and either (a) commit its Dockerfile to source control so you can `docker build` it; or (b) `docker push` the existing image to a repository; or else (c) `docker save` the image to a file.  Then you could run a new container based on that image on the new system.